# About autoencoder and semantic segmentation using Unet

Tags: autoencoder, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am trying to preprocess 1600 images using autoencoder and then use the weight to train UNET for semantic segmentation.

Question 1: Do I need to use the same number of images for pre-train autoencoder and Unet for getting the best IOU?

Question 2:

```py
img_data=[]
path1 = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Skull images'
files=os.listdir(path1)

for i in tqdm(files):
    img=cv2.imread(path1+'/'+i,1)   #Change 0 to 1 for color images
    img=cv2.resize(img,(SIZE, SIZE))
    img_data.append(img_to_array(img))

img_array = np.reshape(img_data, (len(img_data), SIZE, SIZE, 3))
img_array = img_array.astype('float32') / 255
```

The program is crashing on google colab as img_array uses excessing memory. Now how to do this without crashing? the image sizes are 512*512.

Answer (score 0):

you need to train the Auto-encoder on part of your dataset, then use the gained weights to train u-net on the whole dataset, try to resize the images 256x256